# What is the best way for various meaning slug in Laravel Routing?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

for perfect SEO, I need the following url structure.

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-side-hustles**

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-san-francisco-side-hustles**

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-san-francisco-94804-side-hustles**

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/vacation-home-rentals-side-hustles**

for above urls, I can make the Laravel Route like this.

```
Route::get('{id}side-hustles', function ($id) {
});
```

but I have a problem on this. I am in finding the best way for working, because the above 4 urls have to get the each other results.

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-side-hustles**

`california` => state param

by using this param, I need to retrieve the results from the database.

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-san-francisco-side-hustles**

`california` => state param

`san-francisco` => city param

by using these 2 params, I need to retrieve the results from the database.

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-san-francisco-94804-side-hustles**

`california` => state param

`san-francisco` => city param

`94804` => zip code param

by using these 3 params, I need to retrieve the results from the database.

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/vacation-home-rentals-side-hustles**

`vacation-home-rentals` => object param title

by using this param, I need to retrieve the object from the database

totally, above 4 url rules will have the same format like this `{slug}-side-hustles`. their process will not be same.

for this, what is the best way on laravel routing?

Comment: Separate it like : `/country/city`, `/country` this is much more seo friendly. I used like this on my blog

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to simplify.

Using your URLs as example:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-side-hustles

http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-san-francisco-side-hustles

http://127.0.0.1:8000/california-san-francisco-94804-side-hustles

You could use the following

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/{state}/{article}](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7Bstate%7D/%7Barticle%7D)

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/{state}/{city}/{article}](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7Bstate%7D/%7Bcity%7D/%7Barticle%7D)

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/{state}/{city}/{zipcode}/{article}](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7Bstate%7D/%7Bcity%7D/%7Bzipcode%7D/%7Barticle%7D)

And in the controller(s), you can create dedicated methods for each route.